# Python squaring ints in a list from a file

Tags: python

I am trying to overwrite the numbers in a list that was inputted through a file with their respective squares. I have:

```
def squareEach():

    fname = input("Enter exact file name: ")
    infile = open(fname, 'r')
    data = infile.readlines()
    nums = []
    nums1 = []

    for i in range(len(data)):
        nums.append(data[i].split())
        nums1.append(nums[i] ** 2)

    print(nums1)

squareEach()
```

but am getting an error. Any help?

Comment: nums1.append(nums[i] ** 2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'

Comment: It's a text file with a list of ints separated by spaces

Comment: Could you supply a short example of your input text file and your expected input?  As others have pointed out, you are possibly trying to square a list of strings.  Easily solved but we would know exactly what your inputs and expected outputs are.

Answer (score 0):

`data[i].split()` returns a `list`, so you append a `list` to your variable `nums`.

Then, you try to `nums[i] ** 2` . However, nums contains lists of integers, so `nums[i]` is a list, and you can't square a `list`

Instead of appending `data[i].split()`, you should append an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input file looks like this:

```
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
```

Then this line of code:

```
nums.append(data[i].split())
```

Creates a two-element list such as `['4', '16']` and puts it in `nums`.  Therefore, `nums` is a list of lists, and you'll have to subscript it twice: once to get the desired sublist, and once again to get the element within the sublist, like so:

```
nums[i][0]
```

And since the items are stored as strings, you'll need to call `int()` on those values if you want to do calculations.

Answer (score 0):

If the read data is returned in the following format:

```
data = ["1 2 3 4 5 6","7 8 9"]
```

Then the following code would correctly populate two lists, one with the **Integer** values and the second with the **squares**:

```
num = []
num1 = []

for line in data:
    for num_string in line.split():
        integer  = int(num_string)
        num.append(integer)
        num1.append(integer**2)
```